# Adding image to UITableView footer

Tags: ios, ios5

Does anyone out there know how to add an image to the UITable Footer?

Answer (score 2):

Respond to [`tableView:viewForFooterInSection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForFooterInSection%3a) by creating a UIImageView for your image. Also make sure to respond to [`tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForFooterInSection%3a).